# Open With Support

Tags: c#, contextmenu

I want to be able to open a file using Open With, I know how to add it to the list but when I open something, such as a .txt file using my program, nothing happens.

Say I opened **C:\chapter_1.txt** using my program, how could I find the directory of what was opened?

There are a few other questions about this but none of them seem to really answer my question (I'm new to C# so its a little complicated for me)

Comment: The full path to the file will be passed as a command line argument.

Comment: @Oliver Kubicki, I am not full understand your meaning, What do you mean about 'uisng open with'? I think it will better for you to add some code to describe your problem better.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT When you open a .txt file with Notepad, it will read the file contents and import it. How could I find the directory of the file that was opened so I can read the contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the args parameter to get the path from the opened file.

For example, I make a console app and I used open with to open the txt file.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = "";
    if(args.Length>0)
    {
        path = args[0];
        Console.WriteLine(path);
    }

    string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

After opening with the console exe, we will get the file path and file content.

[image]

Update: Winform

Code:

```
namespace TestWinform
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string []args)
        {
            
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            if(args.Length==0)
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1(""));
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1(args[0]));
            }
 
        }
    }
}



 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1(string path)
        {
           
            InitializeComponent();
            this.textBox1.Text = path;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: But how would I be able to put the text into a richTextBox? It is a static void so I'm unable to reference the textbox.

Comment: @Oliver Kubicki， I have updated winform related code. I set a textbox for it.

Comment: This works but I'm unable to use the path for File.ReadAllText when the path variable is empty.

Comment: I was able to fix it with a String.IsNullOrEmpty. Thanks!